# Is circular type reference a bad thing to do In TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, eslint, es6-module-loader

I encountered below code snippets which contain a cyclic importing dependency on type reference.

```js
// Foo.ts
import { Bar } from './Bar';
export interface Foo {
  isBarOK: (bar: Bar) => boolean;
}

// Bar.ts
import { Foo } form './Foo';
export class Bar {
  protected readonly foo: Foo;
}
```

This is a simplified version but it explains the case I encountered. `tsc` has no problem in compiling the code, but I got a warning from the [import/no-cycle](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-cycle.md) ESLint rule. We can see that `Foo` and `Bar` references each other for typing. Is this a bad practice? What impacts does it imply?

Comment: This [blog](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de) on how to resolve nasty circular dependencies in JS/TS provides a pretty smart solution, but it's to solve actual runtime dependency issues.

Comment: Even if ts would be able to manage circular dependencies it has a bad architectural smell.

Comment: @DirkR Yup, I agree architecture wise this needs an improvement. But I want to know just from typing perspective whether this has any implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pure typescript file will not be outputted into your bundle, so you can safely ignore it.

but be careful with javascript file, circular import might mess up tree shaking

Comment: Yup, I did a madge analysis on the transpiled JS files and found no circular dependencies. This is only cyclic type reference.